# Astroquery JPL Horizons Python

Tags: python, astroquery

I'd like to ask if anyone knows how can i get list of all objects that are in the Solar system. I mean all planets and their natural satellites. Or first 400 objects that are the closest to the barycenter of the solar system. The only thing i can get are planets and not exactly planets but their barycenters, so these aren't even correct coordinates.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific.  Do you have a minimum size?  In particular, there are more than 1 million asteroids in the asteroid belt bigger than 1km.  Jupiter has something like 10,000 "trojans" and even Earth has four co-orbiting asteroids.  But before you exclude all asteroids, Ceres is bigger than most moons.

Comment: Sorry. I thought i get email about answer. Yeah. I mean satellites that has known orbits and ephemerides, because i need it for simulations. I would need main planets + pluto and (i don't know how it names) "main moons"? For example

Comment: "Jupiter has 53 named moons and another 26 awaiting official names. Combined, scientists now think Jupiter has 79 moons."

Comment: I need it for my project for university about CUDA. It would be nice have around 200 objects. My problem is that I don't know how got list of these objects. They aren't enumerated from index 1 to 200. [link](https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jplhorizons/jplhorizons.html) In this link are examples where Eros has index 433.

Comment: It can be sorted with size. I just need around 200 of objects. It doesn't matter if it wouldn't be all Jupiters moon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my husband is a planetary astronomer who studies moons of the outer planets (and Pluto).  I thought he'd be able to tell me the answer right off.  His response was "It's complicated, there is no central repository."

Most astronomers use the SPICE Toolkit and its Python wrapper.  This toolkit has built within it databases for many of the objects that astronomers are interested it.

You can also find the ephemeris of most bodies at [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/).  He has only used it to get one ephemeris at a time, but it may have the ability to generate multiple ephemerides.

Information about minor planets (Pluto, Ceres, Pallus, etc) can be found at the [Minor Planet Center](https://minorplanetcenter.net/).

Comment: Thanks! It seems I have to write every celestial object one by one. Unfortunetly it's teodius work.